# Firebase on(child_added) some field 'undefined'

Tags: firebase

I am working on a real time application and i am using firebase with pure html and javascript (not angularJS).

I am having a problem where i saved user's data to firebase with the given code by firebase :

```
var isNewUser = true;
ref.onAuth(function(authData) {
  if (authData && isNewUser) {
    authData['status'] = 'active';
    authData['role'] = 'member';
    ref.child("users").child(authData.uid).set(authData);
   }
});
```

This will add the authData to the `/users/` node. As you can see that i also appended some custom fields to the authData, status and role.

Now i am using this code to get the user's data from firebase and display them.

```
ref4.on("value", function(snapshot) {
    var snapshotData = snapshot.val();
console.log('username: '+snapshotData.status);
});
```

If i use `on('value')`, the status get printed out on the console but if i do it this way,

```
ref4.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  var snapshotData = snapshot.val();
  console.log('status: '+snapshotData.status);
});
```

It is showing undefined for the status. May i know what's wrong and how to fix this problem. Thank you.

Comment: You have `ref4.on("chile_added"` in that last snippet, which should likely be `child_added`. Can we assume that is a typo in the question only and not in your real code?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. It's a typo.

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a JSBin/JSFiddle? It would be helpful to see how you are creating the `ref4` variable and what location it points to.

Comment: This could wouldn't run, considering that you've already shown that status is not an object, and child_added returns the child paths (in this case status, which is a string). Please provide workable examples so you don't burn other devs time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `value` is returning the path provided by ref4, and `child_added` is returning each child of that path, it's unlikely both are going to have a key status.

Consider this data structure:

```
{
   "users": {
      "brucelee": {
          "status": "awesome"
      },
      "chucknorris": {
          "status": "awesomerest"
      }
   }
}
```

If I now query for this according to your incomplete example:

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://<instance>firebaseio.com/users/brucelee');
ref.on('value', function(snap) {
   // requests the brucelee record
   console.log(snap.name(), ':', snap.val().status); // "brucelee: awesome"
});

ref.on('child_added', function(snap) {
   // iterates children of the brucelee path (i.e. status)
   console.log(snap.name(), ':', snap.val().status); // THROWS AN ERROR, because status is a string
});
```

So to do this on child_added with a data structure like this (and presumably somewhat like yours), it would look as follows:

```
ref.on('child_added', function(snap) {
   // iterates children of the brucelee path (i.e. status)
   console.log(snap.name(), ':', snap.val()); // "status: awesome"
});
```